# Java issue with object

Tags: java

I have a class called

```
public class UserSettings {
    public static String sessionId;
    public static  int vrefresh;
    public static  int mrefresh;
}
```

Then in another class I have this method

```
public static void parseBusinessObject(String input, Object output)
```

And this method writes into the output Object.

But in this case there are still static variables, so I can pass the class without creating an object?

Comment: You cannot learn a language in a question-and-answer format. You need to read books, and then come back here when you have some sort of question that cannot be answered by reading books.

Comment: @MikeNakis I'd take issue with that, e.g., [The Little Schemer](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ccs.neu.edu%2Fhome%2Fmatthias%2FBTLS%2Fsample.ps).

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand that this is humor, but I do not understand whether it is in agreement with my comment, or in disagreement.

Comment: @DaveNewton:  Very funny (and you may have a point).

Comment: @MikeNakis How is it humor? I'm disagreeing with you, because you're incorrect. SO isn't the correct *venue* for learning a language in the same fashion, but that's different than the method being invalid.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can you please chat with me? I am at "Programmers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass the class at all, you can write directory to the static property:

```
UserSettings.mrefresh = 42;
```

Whether or not you *should* is a different issue. If you're passing a `UserSettings` as the `Object` parameter (unclear from your post) you can access static members through the instance reference:

```
output.mrefresh = 42;
```

This is considered... sub-optimal: Java conventions access static properties through the class only, not instances, despite the syntactic legality of doing so. But your method takes an `Object`, so you'd need to use reflection or casting based on `instanceOf` results--I'm suspicious of the method itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the variables on `UserSettings` not static (i.e. remove the static modifier), then create a new instance of `UserSettings`, and then pass that to `parseBusinessObject`.

I *think* that is what you intend to do.